# Prove that $AB-BA=I_2$ cannot hold whatever the real $2\times 2$ matries $A, B$

Tags: matrices, real-numbers

How can I prove that $AB-BA=I_2$ cannot hold whatever the real $2\times 2$ matries $A, B$.

Suppose $A=\pmatrix{ a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}}$ and $B=\pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21}& b_{22}}$.

Then $AB=(c_{ij})$, where $c_{ij}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^2a_{ir}b_{rj}, i,j=1,2$ and $BA=(d_{ij})$, where $d_{ij}=\displaystyle\sum_{s=1}^2b_{it}a_{tj}, i,j=1,2.$

Now $AB-BA=I_2\implies c_{ij}-d_{ij}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^2a_{ir}b_{rj}-\displaystyle\sum_{s=1}^2b_{it}a_{tj}$.
$\implies a_{12}b_{21}-b_{12}a_{21}=1, a_{21}b_{12}-a_{12}b_{21}=1,$
   $b_{12}(a_{11}-a_{22})+a_{12}(b_{22}-b_{11})=0,$
   $a_{21}(b_{11}-b_{22})+b_{21}(a_{22}-a_{11})=0$.

From the first two, $a_{12}b_{21}=b_{12}a_{21}$ is ambiguous. Hence the result follows.

I am looking alternative method to show the result. Is there any other way to show this result?

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837381/prove-that-there-are-not-two-matrices-2x2-such-that-ab-ba-i-2

Answer (score 4):

We always have $\operatorname{tr} (AB-BA) = 0$ but $\operatorname{tr} I_n = n$.

Comment: Way to go, copper.hat, +1 from the Caffe Mediterraneum in beautiful downtown Beserkeley!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Wish I was there now instead of fighting (presumably) D68...

Comment: fighting D68?  Missed that one. . .

Comment: @RobertLewis: Some viral respiratory thing. My middle-school son has been out for 3 days with it and I am succumbing... (I hope you do miss it!)

Comment: Man, when the kids get a bug, the whole house goes down!  Best wishes and blessings for a speedy recovery!

Comment: @RobertLewis: The wishes are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Taking the trace on both sides , we have $$trace(AB-BA)=trace(I_2)$$

But $$trace(A+B)=trace(A)+trace(B)$$. Hence $$trace(AB)-trace(BA)=2$$. But $trace(AB)$ is same as $trace(BA)$. hence you get $2=0$ which is absurd.

So the conclusion follows.