# Prove that there are not two matrices 2x2 such that: $AB-BA=I_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried this question by multiplying explicitly the matrices but I think I'm not getting anything, so I think, well let's suppose false so $C(AB-BA)=C$ and find a contradiction but also I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Have you encountered the trace of matrices?

Comment: Hint: $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. Assuming your ground field doesn't have characteristic two. Also, this is surely a duplicate.

Comment: I vote to reopen. This is specifically asking about $2\times 2$ matrices and here brute force can be used.

Comment: See also [this general version](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/99175/11619).

Comment: Here is [another question about $2\times2$ matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954959/prove-that-ab-ba-i-2-cannot-hold-whatever-the-real-2-times-2-matries-a-b). But all solutions there use trace.

Answer (score 2):

You could just brute force it:
$$\begin{align}
A =\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4} \quad
B =\pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4} \\
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
AB - BA 
&= \pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4}\pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4} - \pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4}\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4} \\
&=  \pmatrix{a_1b_1 + a_2b_3& a_1b_2 + a_2b_4 \\ ? & ?} - \pmatrix{a_1b_1 + a_3b_2& ? \\ ? & ?}
\end{align}
$$
Now just show that this can't happen. (Yes, there is work to do for you.)

As you mention in your question, when you have found $AB - BA$, you could (maybe) use that $C(AB - BA) = (AB-BA)C$ for all $C$. For example this would have to be true for 
$$
C = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}
$$
and matrices like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given two matrices $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, we always have $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$ as can be verified by a direct calculation (and in fact, this property characterizes the trace as a linear map uniquely up to normalization). Apply $\operatorname{trace}$ to your equation to obtain a contradiction (assuming $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{F} \neq 2$).

Comment: How does that characterize the trace?

Comment: The trace is the unique linear functional $\varphi \colon M_n(\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ that satisfies $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$ and $\operatorname{trace}(I_n) = n$.

Comment: So by characterizes, you meant "as a linear map". Anyway, it seems strange to specifically put a field into this without noting the possible exceptions (which are probably not relevant for the OP, but still).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the comment, I've edited the answer to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're working over a field with characteristic $\;\neq2\;$ :

$$AB-BA=I_2\implies 0=Tr.(AB)-Tr.(BA)=Tr.(AB-BA)=Tr.(I_2)=2$$